# 1066 - Not unique table/alias:

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you please help me out. I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT `a`.`UNIQ_CODE`, `b`.`JUDUL_BERITA`, `b`.`THUMNAIL`, `c`.`NAMA`, 
       `a`.`TAG`, `a`.`CREATED_DATE`, `a`.`GLOBAL`, `a`.`VERIFIKASI` 
FROM (`q_master_berita` a) 
JOIN `q_master_berita` a ON `b`.`UNIQ_CODE` = `a`.`UNIQ_CODE` 
RIGHT JOIN `q_daftar_user` c ON `a`.`ID_UPLOADER` = `c`.`ID` 
WHERE ( a.FLAG = 'DRAFT' AND a.ID_SEKOLAH = '3824' ) 
ORDER BY `b`.`JUDUL_BERITA` asc 
LIMIT 10
```

And somehow it says

```
Not unique table/alias: 'a'
```

Comment: where is your table name which use alias 'b' ?

Comment: ok this is finished , I already to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using same alias a twice for table q_master_berita. You need to use different aliases.

```
SELECT `a`.`UNIQ_CODE`, `b`.`JUDUL_BERITA`, `b`.`THUMNAIL`, `c`.`NAMA`, 
   `a`.`TAG`, `a`.`CREATED_DATE`, `a`.`GLOBAL`, `a`.`VERIFIKASI` 
FROM (`q_master_berita` a) 
JOIN `q_master_berita` b ON `b`.`UNIQ_CODE` = `a`.`UNIQ_CODE` 
RIGHT JOIN `q_daftar_user` c ON `a`.`ID_UPLOADER` = `c`.`ID` 
WHERE ( a.FLAG = 'DRAFT' AND a.ID_SEKOLAH = '3824' ) 
ORDER BY `b`.`JUDUL_BERITA` asc 
LIMIT 10
```